# exception JPA derby config for junit?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, derby

I have a config file `persistence.xml` as mentioned below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
<persistence-unit name="entity"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> 
         <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
        <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"     value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:derby:src/test/resources/sql/entityDB;create=true" >
        <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
            value="database" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and load persistence code as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {      
    String persistenceUnit = "entity";
    Properties pros = new Properties();
    pros.setProperty(PersistenceUnitProperties.ECLIPSELINK_PERSISTENCE_XML,
        "src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml");
    // Get the entity manager for the tests.
    entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnit,pros);
    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select * from entityTables");
    List<Entity> todoList = q.getResultList();

    entityManager.close();
}
```

But when I am calling `createEntityManagerFactory` I am getting bellow exception:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException:No Persistence provider for EntityManager named entity

How can I fix it?

Comment: And is EclipseLink in your CLASSPATH? Also createQuery is for JPQL queries, and "SELECT * FROM entityTables" is not JPQL

Comment: he will not need to add it in the classpath if he uses the HibernatePersistence.

Comment: If "he uses Hibernate persistence" he will have to have Hibernate in the CLASSPATH. If "he uses EclipseLink" he will have to have EclipseLink in the CLASSPATH. FFS

Comment: I'm using EclipseLink. In my opinion, I think the problem is in the configuration, but I can not see it

Comment: Your "configuration" says "look for EclipseLink JPA". Your message says "I cannot find EclipseLink JPA in the CLASSPATH". So tell us what is in the CLASSPATH?

Comment: The error comes when the Persistence class goes through the list of providers available looking for one to load the "entity" persistence unit.  Both the EclipseLink jars and the persistence.xml file need to be available.  Since the file you are passing in is already named persistence.xml, you shouldn't need the ECLIPSELINK_PERSISTENCE_XML property to specify the file name - make sure you package it up and it is available on the classpath - is src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml is a source directory, so I think it likely your classloader can't see it

Answer (score -1):

After `<persistence-unit name="entity" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">`, use the persistence provider name:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

Edit : or put in the classpath of the manifest this packages : - persistence.jar - eclipselink.jar

Comment: you mean the line he already has, selecting EclipseLink as JPA provider?

Comment: yes, may be the eclipse Persistence provider causing this issue.

Comment: The answer to that is not to throw away the provider he uses; it is to investigate WHY.

Comment: thank for help, but i'm using eclipselink not hibernate ! :))